# Migration time created of node

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm flowing [article](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-8-migrations-part-4-migrating-nodes-drupal-7) to migration my data. Every fields is working fine. But field **created** doesn't working. Field created always insert time import.

I try replace field created with setting

```
created:
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: 1389312000
```

but same result. **So how to migration time created of node?**

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your source plugin isn't supplying the `created` field to do what is done in the reference article:

`source:
  plugin: custom_article
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  bundle: article
process:
  ...
  created: created`

This part of the source plugin config is saying, "import `article` nodes by setting its `created` field from the source column `created` generated by the `custom_article` plugin".

Adding:

```
created:
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: 1389312000
```

Is telling the migration to "set `created` to `1389312000` as a default (if there's no source plugin data"

If you're copying the reference article's `modules/migrate_custom/src/Plugin/migrate/source/Article.php`, you'll need to make sure your plugin's `query()` method is correctly querying its source so that's available for processing and

```
process:
  ...
  created: created
```

Is set in your migration config so that it's sourced correctly.